# My html have some error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I don't know what i am missing help me thank you

When i click check it return wrong();

And it should return yes(); because they both are same value and result.

but its giving only wrong();

I want if value and Result is same then it should do yes();

**Solved example here thanks all for helping out me.**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Your title</title>

    <link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Get</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check(Content) {
            var Right = "Yes";
            var Wrong = "No";
            var Result = "100";
            var value = "100";
            if (Result == 'value') {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Right;
            }else {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Wrong;
            };
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What you need to get..??

Comment: I think you mean `if (Result == value)`

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling the right function.

```
<button onclick="check()">Get</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to try this :---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Your title</title>

        <link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Get</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check(Content) {
                var Right = "Yes";
                var Wrong = "No";
                var Result = "100";
                var value = "100";
                if (Result == 'value') {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Right;
                }else {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Wrong;
                };
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will work fine and keep in your mind always try to call a defined function!!..

Follow code like this. it will help you!!

Answer (score 1):

You try to call non existing `myFunction()` function instead of `check()` in your onclick.

There're tools called **validators** that can help you checking your markup, CSS, JS for any issues. Some are paid, but you can easily find free ones, like this: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you expect clicking on button to call your function, then you should at very least call it with same name in both places (call and definition), right now you have `myFunction` and `check`.

Additionally you compare `Result` with literal string `'value'`, not what's inside variable `value`. Remove those quotes to make it work.

Your second example still have wrong comparison and while you do call `yes()` and `wrong()`, I don't see you returning their value as in `return yes()`. Unless they do something by themselves, you're just throwing their result away.

Comment: Thanks While making it short to understand i messed my all code.

Comment: @SoniSharma, updated for newer source.

Comment: Check new one please the old i made too simple and people already hate it lol

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to initiate the function on click of your "Get" button, then your function is incorrectly named. You are calling "myFunction" but the actual function is called "check". Do this instead:

```
<button onclick="check()">Get</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not have javascript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction():">Get</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var Right = "Yes";
    var Wrong = "No";
    var Result = "100";
    var value = "100";
    if (Result == 'value') {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Right;
    }else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Wrong;
    };
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function name

```
<script>
function myFunction(Content) {
   var Right = "Yes";
   var Wrong = "No";
   var Result = "100";
   var value = "100";
   if (Result == 'value') {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Right;
    }else {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Wrong;
   };
```

};
     
and what is Content you are passing to your function then onclick you must pass it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have called JS function "myFunction()" on button click event but you have declared function with wrong name and paramenter in javascript.

You should declare function as below in javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var Right = "Yes";
    var Wrong = "No";
    var Result = "100";
    var value = "100";
    if (Result == 'value') {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Right;
    }else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Wrong;
    };
};
</script>
```

After doing above changes, May be you will get your solution.